# If $\mu$ is a signed finite measure, then $\|\mu\| = \sup \left\{ \int f d\mu : |f| \leq 1 \right\} $

Tags: measure-theory, integration

If $\mu$ is a signed finite measure, then

$$
\|\mu\| = \sup \left\{ \int f d\mu : |f| \leq 1 \right\}
$$

I did the inequality "$\geq$". Somebody help with the other inequality "$\leq$"?

Comment: How do you define $\|\mu\|$?

Comment: @gnometorule This is the total variation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_measure

Comment: @gnometorule: Ah sorry, well $||\mu|| = |\mu|(X)$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By Hahn decomposition theorem, there exist two measurable sets $P,N$ such that $P\cup N=X$ and $P\cap N=\emptyset$, and $\mu(A\cap P)\geq 0$ while $\mu(A\cap N)\leq 0$ for all measurable sets $A$.

Now let
$$
f=1_P-1_N.
$$

We have
$$
\int_Xfd\mu=\mu(P)-\mu(N)=|\mu|(X).
$$

So the reverse inequality follows.

Comment: @Malaq You're welcome. I'm glad I could help.